# python image size function in PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am using the PIL package in python and I want to import the pixels into a matrix after I convert it to grayscale this is my code

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

imo = Image.open("/home/gauss/Pictures/images.jpg")

imo2 = imo.convert('L')
dim = imo2.size
pic_mat = np.zeros(shape=(dim[0] , dim[1]))

for i in range(dim[0]):
    for j in range(dim[1]):
        pic_mat[i][j] = imo2.getpixel((i,j))
```

My question is about the size function. it usually returns a tuple `(a,b)` where `a` is the width of the picture and the `b` is the length of the picture, but doesn't that mean that `a` is the column in a matrix and `b` is the row in a matrix. I am wondering this to see if I set up my matrix properly.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try just doing

```
pic_mat = np.array(imo.convert('L'))
```

You can also avoid doing things like `shape=(dim[0] , dim[1])` by slicing the size tuple like this `shape=dim[:2]` (the `:2` is even redundant in this case but I like to be careful...)